# 2D array data retrieval using ID

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

basically I'm creating a small lotto program and I want to do a function where the user would enter his/ or her id and it will give their numbers and lets them know if they are a winner

The players numbers are stored in a 2D array**(not a numpy)** like this `[[2, 17, 19, 19, 21, 29, 8, 17],[9, 5, 17, 18, 23, 28, 2, 2]]` so if a player enters their `id as 1` then it should return the second array completely, As I want to check if that player is a winner or not.

I have done the below but it doesn't work, the player checking part does work when I run it separately

`IndexError: list index out of range`

```
player = [[2, 17, 19, 19, 21, 29, 8, 17],[9, 5, 17, 18, 23, 28, 2, 2],[5, 8, 18, 18, 29, 30, 25, 26],[5, 6, 15, 13, 23, 24, 12, 12]]
win = [2, 17, 19, 19, 21, 29, 8, 17]
group1 = set(win[0:6])
group2 = set(win[6:8])
playerID = int(input("Please enter player ID "))
print(playerID)
print(player[playerID])
for i in player[playerID]:
    count = 0
    for j in range(6):
        x = player[i][j]
        if x in group1:
            count+=1
            print("score")
        if j == 5:
            if count == 6:
                print("You are a winner")
            elif count == 5:
                print("You win with 5 numbers" )
            elif count == 4:
                print("You win with 4 numbers")
            elif count == 3:
              print(  "you win with 3 numbers")
            elif count < 3:              
                    count2 = 0
                    for l in range(6,8):
                        y = player[i][l]
                        if y in group2:
                            print("you win with bouns numbers")
            else: 
                print("sorry you lose")
```

Answer (score 0):

You got me confused at first.  You are not using an array, but a list of lists.  Arrays are something specific in python (from the array module), and are always 1D.

Having said that, your code (using a list of lists) is correct. You will only get the error message if the user keys in and ID >3.